# ASP.NET Core: Load the actually rendered text from a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

Im looking for a simple way to get a string from a URL that contains all text actually displayed to the user.

I.e. anything loaded with a delay (using JavaScript) should be contained. Also, the result should ideally be free from HTML tags etc.

A straightforward approach with WebClient.DownlodString() and subsequent HTML-regex is pretty much pointless, because most content in modern web apps is not contained in the initial HTML document.

Comment: How about [Html Agility Pack](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack)?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you can use Selenium WebDriver to fully load the page and then dump the full DOM.